# How to Find difference between two values of last two dates in R program

Tags: r, data-analysis

```
DF2
Date         EMMI      ACT      NO2
2011/02/12   12345     21       11
2011/02/14   43211     22       12
2011/02/19   12345     21       13
2011/02/23   43211     13       12
2011/02/23   56341     13       12
2011/03/03   56431     18       20
```

I need to find difference between two dates in a column. For example difference between ACT column values.For example, the EMMI 12345, Difference between dates 2011/02/19 - 2011/02/12 = 21-21 = 0. like that i want to do for entire column of ACT. Add a new column diff and add values to that. Can anybody let me know please how to do it.

This is the output i want

```
DF3
Date         EMMI      ACT      NO2  DifACT
2011/02/12   12345     21       11    NA
2011/02/14   43211     22       12    NA
2011/02/19   12345     21       13    0
2011/02/23   43211     13       12    -9
2011/02/23   56341     13       12    5
```

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you want.

Comment: Hi Dason, What i want to do is i want to find the difference two values in the ACT column for all the rows. However the problem is i need it to be done for each EMMI. As you can see from above dataframe that EMMI-12345 has two dates 2011/02/2012 and 2011/02/19 so i want to subtract those two dates with their ACT column values.

Comment: Please show the intended output. If I understand you correctly (I'm not sure I do) you could use `ddply` from plyr or one of the other split-apply-combine functions.

Comment: i added my final out put above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DF3 <- DF2
DF3$difACT <- ave( DF3$ACT, DF3$EMMI, FUN= function(x) c(NA, diff(x)) )
```

As long as the dates are sorted (within EMMI) this will work, if they are not sorted then we would need to modify the above to sort within EMMI first.  I would probably sort the entire data frame on date first (and save the results of `order`), then run the above.  Then if you need it back in the original order you can run `order` on the results of the original `order` results to "unorder" the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on plyr package (not tested):

```
library(plyr)
DF3<-ddply(DF2,.(EMMI),mutate,difACT=diff(ACT))
```

Comment: I think you need to pad with `NA` as demonstrated by Greg Snow. The length of `diff`'s return value is always one shorter than the length of the input vector.

Comment: And as far as I am aware you can't `diff` on single values because the replacement will be zero rows long.

Comment: @ Roland and @SimonO101 : So, it will be basically the same function within `ddply`..right?